# Should questions about Pathfinder now link to Archives of Nethys over d20pfsrd?

Tags: discussion, answers, pathfinder

An extension of [this other meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3277/pathfinder-sources-prd-vs-d20pfsrd);

Paizo has taken down their own PRD and [officially licensed](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo6sg93?Big-PathfinderStarfinder-Reference-Document-News) the [Archives of Nethys](https://aonprd.com/) page as their reference document. Archives of Nethys provides a community driven resource for all Pathfinder (and Starfinder) content, including setting-specific rule content. It isn't necessarily the easiest to navigate, but it does have the most, current, information and reliable links now that it is no longer an unlicensed source.

Should this make it our official reference as well?

Comment: When you say "taken down their own PRD" is that to say that all (or the vast majority of) current PRD links on our site are now broken links?

Comment: @nitsua60 Not exactly, at least not yet. Links to the old PRD are being redirected to http://legacy.aonprd.com/ . We have about [1099](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22paizo.com%2FpathfinderRPG%2Fprd%22) posts using the PRD though. I checked some and they seem to be redirecting just fine

Comment: By PRD do you mean Pathfinder Reference Document, SRD, or PFSRD, or something else?  I note that they call it the **pfrd** at your link.  *Pathfinder Reference Document: **pfrd.info***  They also refer to the *legacy PRD website* so I am wondering at the abbreviation used ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm not sure on the exact names/proper abbreviations here but what I know is that http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd is what was brought down when archives of nethys was deemed official. After people complained that they liked the old reference, the same pages that were at http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd were then hosted under http://legacy.aonprd.com/ by archives of nethys with old links being redirected as well. (I do notice that the base link is not redirected there but for example http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/classOptions/rogue.html does)

Comment: @sdjz OK, thanks, I am trying to get a grasp on the terms and I may be overthinking this.

Comment: Have there been any statements on how long they're going to keep hosting the legacy pages?

Comment: @divibisan There was nothing concrete. At the time of creating this legacy in aon, it was simply stated " I’m sure at some point in the distant future I’ll end up deprecating it, but that will only be once I have the majority of its functionality and content on my own site. Until then, enjoy!" You can check the old announcement [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180925221455/https://aonprd.com/). I don't recall it being mentioned afterwards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per that previously linked question, we do not have an “official” source.  Use what you prefer as a question or answer author or editor.  Nethys, d20pfsrd, something else.

Also, as the links are not broken, you should *not* go on a pogrom of editing a thousand preexisting questions to change the links. Use new ones going forward.